# Segmentation fault (core dumped) ? what is it and why is caused ??? ( doubly circular linked list program in c++)

Tags: c++, doubly-linked-list

My program (its not complete but I would really like to know my error):

```
#include <iostream.h>
using namespace std;
class dcllnode
{
private:
    int data;
    dcllnode *next;
    dcllnode *prev;
public:
    dcllnode(int ele)
    {
        data = ele;
        prev = next;
        next = prev;
    }
    friend class dcll;
};

class dcll
{
private:
    dcllnode *head;
public:
    dcll()
    {
        head = NULL;

    }
    void create();
    void inserts(int ele);
    void inserte(int ele);
    void inserta(int ele, int pos);
    void insertb(int ele, int pos);
    void dels();
    void dele();
    void dela();
    void display();
};
void dcll::create()
{
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        head = new dcllnode(0);
        cout << "list is created";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "list has already been created";
    }
}
void dcll::inserts(int ele)
{
    if (head == NULL)
        cout << "please create the list first ";
    else
    {
        dcllnode *x;
        x = new dcllnode(ele);
        x->prev = head;
        x->next = head->next;
        (head->next)->prev = x;
        head->next = x;
        cout << "list is modified";
    }
}

void dcll::inserte(int ele)
{
    if (head == NULL)

        cout << "please create the list first ";
    else
    {
        dcllnode *x;
        x = new dcllnode(ele);
        x->next = head;
        x->prev = head->prev;
        (head->prev)->next = x;
        head->prev = x;
        cout << "list is modified";
    }
}

void dcll::dels()
{
    if (head == NULL)
        cout << "please create the list first ";
    else
    {
        dcllnode *x;
        head->next = x;
        head->next = x->next;
        (x->next)->prev = head;
        x->next = NULL;
        x->prev = NULL;
        delete(x);
        cout << "list is modified";
    }
}

void dcll::dele()
{
    if (head == NULL)
        cout << "please create the list first ";
    else
    {
        dcllnode *x;
        head->prev = x;
        head->prev = x->prev;
        (x->prev)->next = head;
        x->prev = NULL;
        x->next = NULL;
        delete(x);
        cout << "list is modified";
    }
}
void dcll::display()
{
    if (head == NULL)
        cout << "please create the list first ";
    else
    {
        dcllnode *p = head->next;
        while (p != head)
        {
            cout << "\n" << p->data;
            p = p->next;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    dcll l1;
    l1.create();
    l1.inserte(10);
    l1.display();
    l1.inserts(20);
    return 0;
}
```

The segmentation problem is not occurring when I use only the create function.  I would like to know how to solve such problems and how to avoid segmentation errors in future any information and/or help is appreciated.

Comment: `dcllnode`'s constructor makes sure that both `prev` and `next` have the same indeterminate value. You're not going to be able to use them. I would recommend that you start with a singly-linked list for pointer practice.

Comment: i have done singly linked list ... i was able to execute it without any glitch .........

Answer (score 1):

You typically get segmentation faults when using illegal pointers (null or uninitialized pointers, or pointers pointing to unallocated or otherwise illegal memory).

In your case it's easy to see what *one* of the problems are, it's in the `dcllnode` constructor where you do

```
prev = next;
next = prev;
```

When you do these assignments the pointers `next` and `prev` are uninitialized, and their values are *indeterminate*. Assigning them to each other like this will not initialize them, just make them both have the same indeterminate value. Later when you dereference these pointers you will have [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) leading to your segmentation fault and the crash.

What you *probably* should to is to initialize both pointers to null:

```
prev = nullptr;  // or 0
next = nullptr;  // or 0
```

<sub>[Note: In C++ don't use `NULL`, use either `nullptr` (preferred) or if you don't have it then plain `0`.]</sub>

Comment: i tried with prev = 0 and next = 0 .. still the same error

Comment: and if it is a circular list      (head->next)->prev = x;
(head->prev)->next = x;       they wont be null right ?

Answer (score 1):

To complete joachim's answer, in these two statements:

```
(head->next)->prev = x;
(head->prev)->next = x;
```

head->next and head->prev can be nullptr so you have to check it before dereferencing the pointer.